# Cake build.ps1 fails to install Cake

Tags: c#, cakebuild

We use the standard build.ps1 PowerShell script supplied from Cakebuild.net

It's worked splendid on both CI and developer machines, but for 1 of our developers we get the following error when launching build.ps1

```
Unable to find package 'Cake'
```

And then exits, checking tools folder there's no Cake installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error you're getting is because NuGet console can't find the Cake package among the configured feeds on the machine.

You can test this theory by changing the following line in [build.ps](https://github.com/cake-build/resources/blob/b9b51309be2124743e318ee638293333a1edc06c/build.ps1#L168)

```
$NuGetOutput = Invoke-Expression "&`"$NUGET_EXE`" install -ExcludeVersion -OutputDirectory `"$TOOLS_DIR`""
```

To

```
$NuGetOutput = Invoke-Expression "&`"$NUGET_EXE`" install -ExcludeVersion -OutputDirectory `"$TOOLS_DIR`" -Source `"https://www.nuget.org/api/v2`""
```

If that works your colleagues machine likely lacks or have the standard nuget.org feeds disabled on his machine.

You can list which sources you have configured by using the NuGet console like this (*if you don't have nuget console in path it should be avail in the repo tools folder*)

```
nuget sources list
```

It should then list v2 and/or v3 feed for nuget.org and they should have the text `[Enabled]` after them like below

```
Registered Sources:

  1.  https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/ [Enabled]
      https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
  2.  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json [Enabled]
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

If they're listed but disabled you can enable them by typing

```
nuget source enable -Name https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
```

Or

```
nuget source enable -Name  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

Depending on which feed you have registered & disabled, if the sources are missing then you can add them by typing

```
nuget sources add -Name https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/ -Source  https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
```

Settings are stored in `%AppData%\NuGet\NuGet.config` so you could manually edit that file, to make sure everyone uses same sources in team you could add a `NuGet.config` to the root of the repository as nuget tries to find config in path and then falls back to app data.

Comment: Wow that answer was actually spot on! Did a `nuget sources list` on devs machine and nuget.org was disabled. Enabling it worked like a charm, thanks!

![disabled](http://i.stack.imgur.com/31acI.png)