# C# catch(FileNotFoundException) and CA1031

Tags: c#, code-analysis

So this code triggers `CA1031`.

```
try
{
    // logic
}
catch (FileNotFoundException) // exception type
{
    // handle error
}
```

While this one does not:

```
try
{
    // logic
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) // exception var
{
    // handle error
}
```

Because the exception type is meaningful, I don't need the `ex` in the first example. But it's not a a general exception type. It's not `IOException` or `Exception`. So why does it still trigger the `CA1031`?

So is there a difference between `catch(FileNotFoundException)` and `catch(FileNotFoundException ex)` outside the fact that I don't capture exception info?

Comment: [This doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1031?view=vs-2019) implies that `FileNotFoundException` shouldn't trigger CS1031. I'd say if your first snippet triggers CA1031, then CA1031 is a bit broken. There's no difference between your two snippets (other than the second one lets you access `ex` of course)

Comment: If you're not using `ex`, Code Analysis is forcing you into a *compiler* warning for an unused variable. *Code Analysis* warnings are secondary.

Comment: @canton7 Not quite, that doc's example does give the exception variable a name, but doesn't actually use it.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian Right, but the very fact that it says `Fix the first violation by catching a specific exception` implies that `FileNotFoundException` is specific enough not to trigger the warning. So the problem is that CS1031 is incorrectly firing on the first snippet, not that it's incorrectly *not* firing on the second.

Comment: I'm coding right now in VS2019 and it triggers it. Not Preview version, latest stable version. @canton7

Comment: Possibly related bug: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/2518

Comment: Update the latest FxCop analyzers package, it used to be an issue. Great question as well.

Comment: @canton7 I agree that the `FileNotFound` exception is probably sufficiently specific that code could reasonably not inspect it and also not rethrow it and still be in a well-determined state.  Just pointing out that the documentation example is consistent with the behavior.

Comment: This is/was definitely a bug

Comment: You can suppress it `[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1031")]`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I know I can but it just did not make any sense to happen in the first place. That's why I was wondering if it's something I'm missing in the way you catch exceptions.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Put an answer with the bug fix and all and I'll approve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So this code triggers **CA1031**

```
try
{
    // logic
}
catch (FileNotFoundException) // exception type
{
    // handle error
}
```

This occurs because a "general exception such as `System.Exception` or `System.SystemException` is caught in a catch statement, or a general catch clause such as catch() is used". To fix it, assign it and handle the error and or rethrow the general exception for it to be handled further up.

Upon further investigation, it seems this *used* to be an bug, you can see more [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/pull/2519/commits/37cb4d6a9867be2a6eb4d1cd7f94a9b58d980216); it was a `Roslyn` issue for `FxCop`.

**To Fix:**
Just update the latest FxCop analyzers package and it should go way.

**NuGet:**

```
 Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers -Version 2.9.7
```

References:
[CA1031](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1031?view=vs-2019)

Comment: LOL install it :P sorry had to do that https://stackoverflow.com/q/38792473/125981

Comment: FWIW: If you still have the **Microsoft Code Analysis 2019** extension installed in Visual Studio, like I did, you'll still get this false positive even if your `FxCopAnalyzers` NuGet package is using the latest version. I was initially confused by that since the extension is at 3.0.0, which is the same as the latest version of `FxCopAnalyzers`. But the versions aren't aligned between the extension and the NuGet package. After disabling or uninstalling the extension, you also need to restart Visual Studio before the change takes effect, and these `CA1031` false positives go away.

Answer (score -4):

I have two Articles I use as basis for my Exception handling:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/
- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

I also link those often when I notice Exception handling errors.

FileNotFound is clearly a exogenous Exception, so it is correct to catch it. However those articles also tell that as a general rule, to always **log or expose** those Exceptions. Ideally the result of Exception.ToString(). If you do not have a way to reference the caught exception, how could you do either of those two? You can only give a generic error message, but with *none of the details you will actually need to debug it*.

While there are many cases where you only want to expose the Exception type to the *user*, there is never one where you only want to *log* the Exception type. The linked articles mention that explicitly, but due to downvotes and comments it seems nessesary for me to repeat that.

So it is one of those cases where the argument is still going if it is a *bug* or a *feature*.

For me it certainly feels more like a feature. I would certainly call you out as potentiall issue, if I saw it in your code. It avoids you under-logging stuff. You could test if the error persist if you write `throw;` at the end of the catch block. This will re-throw on the exception, so a lack of being able to reference the exception in this ExceptionHandler would not be critical.

Comment: I can see **a lot** of case where exception handling would be possible and preferable with only the exception type and not the instance of the actual exception.

Comment: @JustinLessard There are many cases where only *exposing* the Exception type to the user is a good idea. But none where only *logging* the type is a good idea. This is all Discussed in the Linked Articles. And you either log in the handler or throw on for a higher order logging handler to deal with it.

Comment: First article is non-sense. OutOfMemoryException is good example of exception which can be easily recovered.

Comment: @EvgenyGorbovoy No, they can not. Whatever object triggered that exception, is no longer in a valid state. And you can not just remove it, because the code that created and used it still expect it to be there. It is sheer folly to go on after a OOM.

Comment: Let me just show an example:  

try{ Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(path)) } catch(OutOfMemoryException) { Console.WriteLine("Not enough memory to read the file. Try to close other applications  and try again."); continue; }

As you can see, combination of WriteLine and continue the loop perfectly recover the application.