# .net core application showing CA1031 Error code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am getting a **CA1031** error for the below code.
I have modified the editorconfig file in FxCop, but still I am getting the error

> *dotnet_code_quality.CA1031.disallowed_symbol_names = ExceptionType|NullReferenceException*

My code is:

```
catch (Exception e)
     {
     LogMessage("ERROR MESSAGE");
     LogMessage(e.StackTrace);
     }
```

Comment: Your catch block generates CA1031 which says "Do not catch general exception types" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1031?view=vs-2019 Drop the Exception e and rethrow or configure which exception types are disallowed from being caught.

Comment: I tried DROP the exception, but still i am getting the error. ?

Comment: Please refer to this discussion and try it ：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58648645/c-sharp-catchfilenotfoundexception-and-ca1031

Comment: Thanks @YongqingYu.  I already fixed the code by that way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer :

```
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
LogMessage("File Missing Error : ");
LogMessage(e.StackTrace);
}
```